# Add column to elements within list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, apply

I have a list of data frames where some have  a `need` column and others do not. How do I add the `need` column to the other data frames (with value = `NA`)? I've tried using Map or lapply

```
test <- list(data.frame(need = NA, dont_need = NA),
             data.frame(dont_need = NA),
             data.frame(dont_need = NA, dont_need_2 = NA))
```

## Desired Output

```
[[1]]
  need dont_need
1   NA        NA

[[2]]
  dont_need need
1        NA   NA

[[3]]
  dont_need dont_need_2 need
1        NA          NA   NA
```

I can't just use a bind because this list is dynamically created and sometimes only includes one dataframe that doesn't have the `need` column. The answer must also work when this is the case:

```
test_2 <- list(data.frame(dont_need = NA))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `purrr` possibility for situations when there are only empty elements could be:

```
map(test, ~ list_modify(., need = NA))

[[1]]
  need dont_need
1   NA        NA

[[2]]
  dont_need need
1        NA   NA

[[3]]
  dont_need dont_need_2 need
1        NA          NA   NA
```

If there could be existing non-empty elements:

```
map(test, ~ if(!"need" %in% names(.)) update_list(., need = NA) else .)
```

Comment: you should include `library(purrr)` in your answer to make it clearer for people who don't know it.

Comment: Actually this answer will remove the values in the `need` columns if they already exist and are not `NA`

Comment: @Gallarus that's the reason why I actually also included a solution for non-empty existing elements.

Comment: arf my bad, I was too fast in my judgment, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Another version using `lapply` and `is.null`. I added some real values in the initial `data.frame` to show that they are kept if present initially.

```
test <- list(data.frame(need = c(NA, 2), dont_need = 1:2),
             data.frame(dont_need = 1:3),
             data.frame(dont_need = 1:3, dont_need_2 = NA))
> [[1]]
> need dont_need
> NA         1
>  2         2
> 
> [[2]]
> dont_need
>  1
>  2
>  3
> 
> [[3]]
> dont_need dont_need_2
>  1          NA
>  2          NA
>  3          NA


test <- lapply(test, function(df) {
  if (is.null(df[["need"]])) 
    df[["need"]] <- NA

  df
})

> [[1]]
> need dont_need
>  NA         1
>   2         2
> 
> [[2]]
> dont_need need
>  1   NA
>  2   NA
>  3   NA
> 
> [[3]]
> dont_need dont_need_2 need
>  1          NA   NA
>  2          NA   NA
>  3          NA   NA
```

Comment: Thank you! In my haste to make a repex I realized that not having values in the original data frame confuses the answer, since below people have suggested replacing all need with NA.

Comment: The `purrr` answer from @tmfmnk is actually correct and I was wrong. I provides a version  that does not removes the values already present

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward way using `lapply`:

```r
test <- list(data.frame(need = NA, dont_need = NA),
             data.frame(dont_need = NA),
             data.frame(dont_need = NA, dont_need_2 = NA))


lapply(test, function(df) {
  if (!"need" %in% colnames(df)) {
    df$need <- NA
  }
  return(df)
})
#> [[1]]
#>   need dont_need
#> 1   NA        NA
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   dont_need need
#> 1        NA   NA
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   dont_need dont_need_2 need
#> 1        NA          NA   NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that checks the columns names of each `data.frame` for `need` and then create it if it's not there.

```
test2 <- lapply(test, function(x) {
  if(!"need"%in% colnames(x)){
    x$need <- NA
  }
  return(x)
})

[[1]]
  need dont_need
1   NA        NA

[[2]]
  dont_need need
1        NA   NA

[[3]]
  dont_need dont_need_2 need
1        NA          NA   NA
```